# Mocking simple-salesforce

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, simple-salesforce

I'm new to mocking API calls in Python and can't find any documentation that shows any straightforward examples of how to mock calls to an API that uses Requests.

In particular, I need to mock calls to simple-salesforce. I've tried using Reponses and requests-mock, but I always hit some exception or another in the simples-salesforce library.

Can anyone help me with a simple mock of this call? If I can get one to work, I think i can probably get on well from there. Here's my login call:

```
self.salesforce = Salesforce(
        username=username,
        password=password,
        security_token=token,
        instance_url=self.instance_url,
        domain=self.sandbox,
        proxies=proxies,
    )
    return result
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is `patch` the `Salesforce` symbol where it is being used (the module you're trying to test)

You need to make sure that the `Saledforce` symbol itself is a mock. You also need to make sure that when this mock is called, you return another mock object. This is because you're calling the `Salesforce()` method and that is supposed to return a `Salesforce` object.

This might look like this:

```
@mock.patch('full.path.to.your.test.module.Salesforce')
def test_sample(mock_salesforce_constructor):
    mock_salesforce = MagicMock()
    mock_salesforce_constructor.return_value = mock_salesforce

    # set up mock call return values on `mock_salesforce`

    # call your under-test method

    # assert & verify that the mock was called propely
```

You can see more about setting up mock objects here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html